# Web View doesn't load when url is changed internally

Tags: android, url, android-webview

I am using webview as normal way like

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }

    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {

        Toast.makeText(WebViewActivity.this, description, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Now when I search something on google and open any url from list, **it won't load**. It remains a white screen on device. If I load url by code it works! Is that any kind of limitation with webview or I need to enable any other setting of it? Thanx.

Comment: how u r passing result link from google result to webview?? post code

Comment: Won't 'shouldOverrideUrlLoading' do this automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trial and Error worked for me!
just needed to change it like,

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

And it worked as I wanted. Thanx other for putting effort.

Answer (score 1):

Look my solution

```
private void webViewResult() {

    String indexPage = "localhost:8080/libProject/all-book.jsp?classNo="+classtype+"&filename="+subjecttype";
    httpResultWebView = indexPage;
    webview();
```

}

```
void webview() {
    private WebView wv;
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl(httpResultWebView);
    WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
    settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    settings.getAllowContentAccess();
    settings.getJavaScriptEnabled();
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    wv = webView;
    wv.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            String fileName = URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimetype);
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Library", fileName);
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Oh! you are going out of the context...just need to load url

Comment: `private void webViewResult() {
//this is url
    String indexPage = "localhost:8080/libProject/all-book.jsp?classNo="+classtype+"&filename="+subjecttype";
    httpResultWebView = indexPage;
    webview();` and this get url `webView.loadUrl(httpResultWebView);`

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
```

That's not what i'd called the normal way, you should just return false and let the webview handle this. (not too sure why you get the behaviour you described but it might help solve it)

Comment: returned false, nothing changed.

Comment: you also removed the view.loadUrl(url); ?